# How to use email address as a parameter in a rails PUT request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have configured a route in config.rb

```
resources :password
```

When the parameter not an email address, it is working fine.

When the parameter is an email address it will show me the error:

> Started PUT "/password/example@gmail.com.json" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2012-02-22 17:04:17 +0800
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT]
>   "/password/example@gmail.com.json"):

UPDATE1

this is my password controller

```
  def update
    return_info = User.change_password(params[:id],params[:old],params[:newpw],params[:newpw2])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => {:info => t(return_info)} }
    end

  end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you use custom string instead of id try

```
resources :password, :constraints => { :id => /.*/ }
```

Comment: It's working but get another error "Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 8ms"

Comment: I think json mime type is not recognized. Can you try 
respond_with http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with ? And show me values of params (put them to console) 
Let's look into params[:format]

Answer (score 6):

Base64.urlsafe_encode64('robocop@mail.ua')

```
=> "cm9ib2NvcEBtYWlsLnVh"
```

Base64.urlsafe_decode64('cm9ib2NvcEBtYWlsLnVh')

```
=> "robocop@mail.ua"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I don't understand the question properly but perhaps the issue here is that `@` is not a character you can use unencoded in a URL.

I suspect that the email address needs to be encoded before being passed in params and you can do this as follows:

If `email = "hello@mac.com"` try something like

```
URI.escape(email, '@')
```

This will return

```
"hello%40mac.com"
```

Comment: The problem is email address contain "."

Comment: Then try URI.escape(email,'@.')